# Nginx & php on docker containers can't find php files, "file not found"

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I have a basic docker setup with a few containers, one runs nginx, one runs php, one an nginx proxy and one mysql db. All seems to work except for some reason nginx can't seem to see php files, i just get "file not found".

It it definitely pointing to the correct location as html files work fine, it's just php ones.

My docker compose:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  viprs-proxy:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: viprs-proxy
    depends_on:
      - viprs-website
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - viprs-net
  viprs-website:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: nginx
    container_name: viprs-website
    depends_on:
      - php
      - viprs-website-database
    volumes:
      - ./website/nginx/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./website:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - viprs-uploads:/usr/share/nginx/html/wp-content/uploads
    ports:
      - 80
    links:
      - php
    networks:
      - viprs-net
  php:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: php:7-fpm
    container_name: php
    networks:
      - viprs-net
  viprs-website-database:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: viprs-db
    command: --init-file /usr/share/nginx/website.sql
    volumes:
      - ./website.sql:/usr/share/nginx/website.sql
      - viprs-db:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: SOMEPASS
      MYSLQ_DATABASE: viprs
      MYSQL_USER: viprs
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: SOMEPASS
    networks:
      - viprs-net
networks:
  viprs-net:
volumes:
  viprs-uploads:
  viprs-db:
```

The proxy pass works fine but just in case here is the config:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://viprs-website:80;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally here is the actual vhost config on the nginx container with the files:

```
server {
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

I have a basic index.php file in /usr/share/nginx/html where i visit example.com/ and i get the "file not found error", i also get the same error at example.com/index.php - but if i visit example.com/tester.html then this one loads fine

Nginx error log:

```
2022/05/02 14:04:40 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2022/05/02 14:04:40 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.21.6
2022/05/02 14:04:40 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6) 
2022/05/02 14:04:40 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.10.104-linuxkit
2022/05/02 14:04:40 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2022/05/02 14:04:40 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2022/05/02 14:04:40 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 72
2022/05/02 14:04:40 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 74
2022/05/02 14:04:40 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 75
2022/05/02 14:04:40 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 77
2022/05/02 14:04:40 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 79
2022/05/02 14:04:40 [emerg] 72#72: io_setup() failed (38: Function not implemented)
2022/05/02 14:04:40 [emerg] 75#75: io_setup() failed (38: Function not implemented)
2022/05/02 14:04:40 [emerg] 77#77: io_setup() failed (38: Function not implemented)
2022/05/02 14:04:40 [emerg] 74#74: io_setup() failed (38: Function not implemented)
2022/05/02 14:04:40 [emerg] 79#79: io_setup() failed (38: Function not implemented)
2022/05/02 14:04:42 [error] 72#72: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.144.5, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://192.168.144.2:9000", host: "viprs-website"
```

Answer (score 1):

After some more looking around it seems the volume needs to be mounted on both the php and the nginx container and then it starts to work

Comment: Your heads-up saved my day! The FPM requires the volume to locate the PHP file. How could I forget that.